# Firefox Window icon disappeared after interrupted upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, firefox, lubuntu, lxqt

[image: firefox icon]

### Situation

See the attached image: the icon for the Firefox **window** has disappeared after an interrupted upgrade (VM crashed), but the icons on the desktop and in the start menu are fine. (I'm using Lubuntu 20.04 with LXQt DE if that matters.)

### What I did so far

I have tried various ways of fixing the interrupted upgrade, which seem to have done their job well (i.e. finished successfully, no error messages), **including removing/reinstalling Firefox**, but that apparently did not help.

From bash-history:

```
pkg --configure -a
apt-get install -f
apt autoremove
apt-get update --fix-missing
dpkg-reconfigure -a
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get clean
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt install --reinstall firefox
dpkg -P firefox
apt install firefox
```

### Question

How can I **debug** this problem?
In other words, while a command that restores the icon would also be nice, I would like to get a deeper understanding of what went wrong and how it is being fixed.

I.e.:

- where is the Firefox **window** icon supposed to come from?
- how can I check if it is there? (I mean maybe it is not necessarily a stand-alone file, but a resource built into the executable or something similar. In that case, how can I check if that resource is there?)
- how can I find out which package is broken?
- how can I find out that no other packages are broken, due to the interrupted upgrade? (the commands I ran above supposedly fixed the system, but apparently this is not the case, at least for Firefox -- maybe other packages are still broken in subtle ways)

### Remark

I have another VM with the same OS/DE, also upgraded recently (with success), where the window icon is fine. In other words, I assume that it is not a bug in the package.

Answer (score 0):

### I finally found the solution!

**TL;DR:**
Running `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache` made the icon reappear.

**Longer version:**

After various attempts of uselessly removing and reinstalling Firefox, I observed that it was crashing when trying to drag tabs, with the following message:

```
(crashreporter:11662): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:57:15.194: Could not load a pixbuf from /org/gtk/libgtk/theme/Adwaita/assets/check-symbolic.svg.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
```

So it was not Firefox which was broken, but some Gtk icon package.

After some research I found the command above.
(N.B.: I found the command as `/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache` and since that was not working, I first reinstalled the package with `apt-get install --reinstall libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0` -- that may or may not have contributed to the fix, but I have a feeling that it was not the package, which was broken.)